# Why variable in async function returns undefined?

Tags: python, bots, discord

I have a problem. In this code Seer variable at the "if" returns undefined. What's the solution for this?

```
Seer=False

@bot.command(name="watch")
async def setup():
    if(Seer==False):
        Seer=True
        await channel.send("activated")
    else:
        await channel.send("already activated")
```

Comment: Try moving `Seer=False` inside your setup() function if that doesn't break your code logic

Answer (score 0):

Declare Seer variable as `global`

```
@bot.command(name="watch")
async def setup():
    global Seer
    if(Seer==False):
        Seer=True
        await channel.send("activated")
    else:
        await channel.send("already activated")
```